Is azimuth preserved in EPSG:3857?
I am trying to draw the outlines of drone images using OpenLayers. The drone has recorded a "yaw degree", which should be the azimuth. However, when I place the rectangles on the map, their orientation often seems a bit wrong.
I expect them to align along the direction of travel but it often appears as if drone had traveled slightly sideways:

I was starting to wonder whether it might be something to do with the projections. Do I need to somehow transform the angle to make it correct on an EPSG:3857 map?
Here's how I'm drawing those rectangles at the moment:
// We start out having the center coordinates and the bearing from the image metadata
// const center, bearing
// As well estimates of dimensions (using FOV and altitude)
// const width, height

// Create a width x height rectangle around the center
const left = center[0] - (width / 2 / scale)
const top = center[1] + (height / 2 / scale)
const right = center[0] + (width / 2 / scale)
const bottom = center[1] - (height / 2 / scale)

const polygon = new Polygon([[
    [left, top],
    [left, bottom],
    [right, bottom],
    [right, top],
    [left, top],
]])

// and rotate the rectangle around the center
// is this correct?
polygon.rotate(-bearing * Math.PI / 180, center)

feature.setGeometry(polygon)


You really shouldn't do any mapping with mensuration in Web Mercator. All distances are always wrong, so lines of constant bearing isn't going to do you much good. Use a local UTM or  Albers or Lambert Equal-Area Conic.

To avoid projection related problems you could use turf.js library to create rotated rectangles in non projected coordinates (using destination and transformRotate methods), and then project them in OpenLayers.

Thanks @TomazicM, I prepared the polygons via turf and converted only the final polygon, I'm still getting pretty much the same issues. I guess it's just how my bearing data is.

Yes, that would indicate that drone is actually flying a bit sideways or that camera is not attached at the right angle.

DJI drones store a drone yaw in exif tags and a camera gimbal yaw as xmp tags.  Maybe your drone does the same and you have the wrong yaw?  https://exiftool.org/TagNames/DJI.html

@GBG it looks like the gimbal yaw is offset sometimes, others are having a similar issue: https://forum.dji.com/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=285087
